# What exactly does Python's struct.pack do?

Tags: python, pack

Sorry for the stupid question but,

I read the documentation and still can understand what is this function doing:

```
struct.pack('<L',0x01D1F23A)
```

Can someone explain in very childish and detailed manner what this function will do for the given input and for other inputs.

When i print the output i got ":≥╤☺", an ASCII representation of the hex values, so basically how struct.pack is hanging the hex value beside that it turns it to little endian.
How does it stored in memory ? 
I didn't understand what does it "pack's".

Thanks.

Comment: Eh? It's only "hex" while it's text in the config file; once it's parsed, it's a native binary number that's passed to the `pack()` call.

Comment: That's not ASCII; I'm not sure what encoding would map, for example, `F2` to a ≥.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of this is a bytestring (in Python 3), or a standard (non-unicode) string in Python 2, showing 0x01D1F23A represented as an unsigned long in little-endian byte order.

It's "packed" inasmuch as it's stored as raw binary content -- the exact same content you'd have with a native unsigned long type stored natively in memory on a little-endian platform.

[The byte order is specified by the `<`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), and [the unsigned-long type is specified by the `L`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).

This is useful if you're trying to write a file, a network packet, or other content in a native binary format.

Answer (score 1):

It takes several pieces of data (in your case, one piece, L--a 4-byte integer) and puts them into a bytestring

```
>>> struct.pack('<L', 0x01D1F23A) == b'\x3A\xF2\xD1\x01'
True
```

Your confusion could come from several sources

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding